# Does Stack Overflow include graphical programming?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was thinking about how my friend was learning [Scratch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_%28programming_language%29), and he had some questions that I could not answer.

So now I am wondering, does Stack Overflow accept questions about graphical IDEs like Scratch and [Modkit Micro](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/modkit/modkit-electronics-arduino-for-everyone)?

Comment: Yeah, I would appreciate _Scratch_ stuff. I tought my daugther (11) about using it a bit, and it would be very useful for her how to find answers for her particular problems.

Comment: I think adding a *Scratch* tag would be a good idea.

Comment: One thing to note, graphical programming languages are typically eschewed by "real" (professional) programmers, so there may not be a ton of people around to *answer* such questions. Feel free to ask away though!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET _"... eschewed by "real" (professional) ..."_ Pfff, what attitude should this be? How did all of these _professionals_ really learned how to program? For me it was just starting with (re-)typewriting tons of BASIC code for a VC20 from the pertinent magazines available at that time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was worried it could be interpreted that way. I was simply trying to reflect reality, and set an appropriate expectation in case the OP is used to higher traffic tags. Could such a community flourish here? Absolutely. *Will* it? Much harder to say. For the record, I started with the TI version of BASIC and then C++

Comment: @BradleyDotNET _"For the record, I started with the TI version of BASIC"_ LOL, that'*s a good starting point as well, I owned one ages ago, but was pretty bothered to start programming it. /ON-TOPIC Should we at least first create a tag for it? The OP isn't able to do this, and most of the potential communitiy wouldn't be as well. Is there something like a [tag:tag-creation] request on Meta-SO?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You need to have a question first.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As soon as a question appears, they could post a meta question or just  put up a request in chat. Then a higher rep user can add the tag.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot THX for that (obvious) hint. There will be enough of them, don't worry. I could just put up some basic canonicals, remembering what my princess was bothering about. (I'll ask her what were the biggest hurdles of understanding). One of her more serious deficiencies, will be writing proper english (But well, I'd appreciate she's going to be driven to it ;-) ).

Comment: We already have [tag:logo] and [tag:turtle-graphics] tags

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I too learned how to program with TI Basic! I cut my teeth on a Ti-82 and was impressed by the "huge" processor speed increase on the 83

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Basic on an Atari 2600 followed by Basic on a Commodore 64.  Wasn't until I started Windows (and later Web) programming that I worked with graphics.  Having said that, of course Scratch would be welcome!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Such questions, assuming they meet all the other quality requirements, are certainly about programming and would be on-topic here.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any support for graphical code markup, so it appears you will have to take *really* good screen shots to show code.

Comment: _"Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any support for graphical code markup,"_ The more intelligent kid's will find to provide some pseudo-code representations, the graphical blocks used are fairly simple and also have clear meanings and titles.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Indeed, I'm sure any such community would figure out a way to      make markup work for them.

Comment: Ordered lists, inline code, and nested blockquotes should be able to handle the majority of formatting needs for graphical code.

Answer (score 16):

People have been asking questions about Scratch for years already on SO; the appropriate tag is [mit-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-scratch).

To post Scratch code in its familiar graphical representation, use [scratchblocks2](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Block_Plugin). Here's an example I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552374/in-scratch-how-can-you-split-up-a-string-into-a-list-of-characters):

> http://blob8108.github.io/scratchblocks2/#set%20%5Bi%20v%5D%20to%20(0)%0Arepeat%20(length%20of%20(originalString))%0A%20%20change%20%5Bi%20v%5D%20by%20(1)%0A%20%20add%20(letter%20(i)%20of%20(originalString))%20to%20%5Bcharacters%20v%5D%0Aend

[image: screenshot]

How cool would it be to have that tool embedded in SO...

Comment: It should be just "scratch" though.

Comment: Type in 'scratch' in the tag field and you will see 'mit-scratch' and six other tags containing the word 'scratch'. Exactly how popular/widespread/important should a language become before 'scratch' alone is no longer considered ambiguous?

Comment: If it was ambiguous, "language" could be added, as in case of the "iolanguage" tag. But even with the tags you've mentioned I don't find it ambiguous, and on a programming site, preference should be given to programming languages, even if there are other things called just "scratch" (but it seems there are no).

Comment: @BartoszKP: I totally agree with your suggestion of plain 'scratch'; so I took the liberty of creating a [synonym request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283326/rename-tag-mit-scratch-to-scratch).

Comment: Oof! [This is hard to parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991191/how-to-create-a-resetable-timer)! Isn't there a text-only format?

Comment: @Jongware Exactly my point when I referred to scratchblocks2; it takes a **text-based** representation as input. There is tooling to generate the text from a Scratch project. This code is visible _and_ editable for everyone; editing results in a new URL. This makes it possible for repliers to re-post the same code with small adjustments without having to reconstruct all of it. OP in turn can use [ScratchDiff](http://blob8108.github.io/scratchblocks2/diff/) to highlight the changes made by replier. For details and examples, please follow the hyperlinks in my answer.

Comment: It's possible to generate blocks from a snippet. Don't know if that wasn't possible back then but it is now. At least that's one option. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410655/1244884

Comment: I fully agree with this answer. It's very good and clarification request is really needed(+1).

Answer (score 12):

I fully agree with Bradley's answer:

> Such questions, assuming they meet all the other quality requirements, are certainly about programming and would be on-topic here.

There would be a slight problem, to transpose the graphical representation of code to a kind of appropriate pseudo-code markup language, for OP's that don't have enough rep to post images (screen-shots respectively). But this is already dealt in many cases, other (higher rep) users, are editing them in, if they find these appropriate and useful in reviews.

I'd really appreciate a tag like [scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratch), because it would exetend the learning effect for (I'd suspect mostly) the kids, ***how to research*** about their actual problems.
And that's the ***far more important skill vs. mastering the programming language itself*** IMHO, and should be encouraged as much as possible.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No I meant [_'to cope with something'_](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=beherrschen&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) as mentioned from my favorite german english dictionary. I'm not a native speaker, but I thought that would be the best term to use here. (actually I meant _ruling_ it?)

Comment: Perhaps a better term here would be "mastering". "learning" would also be appropriate, but would seem to represent an earlier stage in the process than you are going for. "coping' usually means "to deal with, to survive". If I am "coping" with an illness for example, I am functional while having it, but I certainly haven't beaten or "ruled" it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET THX for the insight. Yes, **mastering** was what I've actually meant. It's hard sometimes to really sort out the right terms. In german I just meant _"Beherrschen"_ (what an awful sound), not _"Überleben"_ (less awful sounding, but simply not appropriate).

Comment: I'll take your word for it on the German (and now I feel like I *really* didn't learn any when I took it :( ) :)