# Rename tag [mit-scratch] to [scratch]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[Scratch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_%28programming_language%29) seems to be gaining popularity. As suggested in a comment on [this answer concerning Scratch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283110/does-stack-overflow-include-graphical-programming/283207#283207), now might be a good time to rename the tag [mit-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-scratch) to just 'scratch'. Or alternatively, to add *scratch* as an alias or synonym for *mit-scratch*; whatever is considered best practice on SO.

There are six other tags containing the word 'scratch', but none of these are programming languages. I don't see a big risk of 'scratch' becoming ambiguous, now or in the near future.

- [scratchbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratchbox)
- [scratchcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratchcard)
- [scratch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratch-file)
- [scratch-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratch-memory)
- [scratchpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratchpad)
- [linux-from-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-from-scratch)

Also keep in mind the target audience of Scratch (children, people with no programming experience); a straightforward tag name might help.

I would like to invite everybody to share their thoughts on this. And after reaching consensus, I hope a moderator can follow up on this?

Comment: For all intents and purposes Scratch isn't really a *proper* programming language, it's a 'Visual' programming language and I personally think the tag shouldn't be changed because of this.

Comment: @cybermonkey Thanks for sharing your opinion. I would appreciate a stronger argument though; I hope you can find the time to post a more elaborate answer. For one, please define "proper"; Scratch is turing-complete, regardless of its main purpose (education) and cutesy-pie visuals. How does Scratch compare to Logo and Visual Basic, in your opinion? Secondly, why should this affect the _name_ of the tag?

Comment: Many professional programmers do not regard Scratch as being a programming language at all, and if you search Meta for Scratch-related opinions you'll find similar opinions. This is primarily because as I said before that Scratch is a so-called 'visual programming language', referring to the fact programs are programmed using a mouse via drag 'n drop rather than a keyboard. It's been a few years since I tried Scratch so it might have evolved slightly since then.

Moreover Scratch problems are related to mostly pure logic than anything related to the actual 'programming language'.

Comment: @cybermonkey A discussion so engrossing, deserves its own room; let's continue elsewhere. Fact is, the tag 'mit-scratch' exists, and has been used for quite some time now. My original post concerns _renaming_ the tag; not its [raison d'être](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raison_d%27%C3%AAtre). If you feel Scratch does not belong on SO, then I suggest you post a new question "please remove tag [mit-scratch]". State your case; include references to those sharing your opinion. Then wait and see how the community responds.

Comment: Alternatively, you can respond to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283110/does-stack-overflow-include-graphical-programming).

Comment: I never said 'this tag shouldn't be allowed', Scratch is a programming language, but simply not a 'proper' one.

Comment: @cybermonkey I don't think "proper" is a well defined term in reference to programming language categorization. Scratch is Turing-complete and Scratch programmers have created neural nets, first-person shooters, and Mandelbrot browsers with it, if that helps. (Disclosure: I work for the Scratch team.)

Answer (score 6):

Personally, it doesn't make a difference. While the language might officially be Scratch, it is also referred to as MIT Scratch pretty often outside of its own website. I'm a former Scratch moderator and current Scratch Wiki admin, although slightly inactive (SE is too addictive...), so I know.

> Also keep in mind the target audience of Scratch (children, people with no programming experience); a straightforward tag name might help.

That's the problem. SE has a 13 year minimum age, and many Scratchers are younger than that. (See http://scratch.mit.edu/statistics/#age)

Comment: That graph though - it shows that *most* scratch users are *at least* 13 years old if you add up the numbers, even if the most common age is 12

Comment: Thanks for your answer; good to hear from an insider! Excellent point about the age limit. But even mature, seasoned SO'ers have [overlooked the 'mit-scratch' tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283110/does-stack-overflow-include-graphical-programming); that's what worries me.

Comment: I would bypass age filters to join the famous community of Stack Overflow in a heartbeat if I were 12. That being said, we could always make `scratch` the original tag and `mit-scratch` a synonym. I think that looks neater.

Comment: In several years of my training hundreds of teachers in Scratch, and observing hundreds of students learning it in dozens of schools, I have never heard a single person or written material use the name "MIT Scratch". (Disclosure: I now work for the Scratch team, but that was all true before I started in June 2018.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, i decided to go ahead and suggest a tag synonym mapping [scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratch) to [mit-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-scratch).

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mit-scratch/synonyms

If you have the required score (5), feel free to vote for it.

Of course, first i had to [create the tag [scratch]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948249/simulating-a-custom-reporter-block-in-scratch)...